# Launching custom implicit intent

Tags: android

Two activities are installed having the following manifest files on device respectively:

The First app's activity has in its manifest:-
where,
    `package="com.example.tictactoe"`

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.tictactoe.YOYO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/*" /> 
 </intent-filter>
```

The second app's activity has in its manifest:-
where,
    `package="com.example.project"`

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.project.YOYO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/*" /> 
 </intent-filter>
```

Now, i want to start one of these activity from third application using the following code:

```
i=new Intent();
i.setAction("YOYO");
i.putExtra("KEY","HII..i am from third app");
startActivity(i);
```

But execution shows an error:-

```
03-11 08:12:30.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 08:12:30.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
                    No Activity found to handle Intent { act=ACTION_SEND (has extras) }
```

Comment: try  Intent i =new Intent("com.example.project.YOYO);//include package startActivity(i);

Comment: **"Now, i want to start one of these activity from third application..."** - Which one? Using "YOYO" as an `action` for the `Intent` isn't enough - you must use the exact name you specify in the `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: @Raghunandan it didnt work...

Comment: @Squonk actually, i want to generate an implicit intent then i want the above mentioned activities to be able to  respond after selection as they will pass the intent-filter.

Comment: the answer by Rvdk should work. Use the package along with the activity class. You were using just the class name.

Comment: @Squonk here, 'YOYO' is a intent name jst like other built-in intent name(like- 'ACTION_SEND') if i will use the full package name along with the intent name...then what would be the benefit of using the implicit intent, i.e. should respond if the intent-filter matches.

Comment: You know that ACTION_SEND is "android.intent.action.SEND". You use the contstant which is that long string.

Comment: @user2155922 : As RvdK points out, `ACTION_SEND` is actually a `static final` field of the `Intent` class which has the value of `android.intent.action.SEND`. Generally the point of an implicit `Intent` is to perform some form of generic action such as to open/view some type of document or send an email etc. In your case you are trying to do something specific with your suite of apps so both of your first two apps should use the same `String` for the `action`, e.g., `com.mycompany.YOYO` and the third app should use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to supply the **full action name**; supply the **mimeType** you used in manifest by calling **setType()** in your intent.

Manifest :

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.example.tictactoe.YOYO" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="text/plain" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Java :

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setAction("com.example.tictactoe.YOYO");
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra("KEY","HI..i am from third app");
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply the full action:

```
i=new Intent();
i.setAction("com.example.tictactoe.YOYO");
i.putExtra("KEY","HII..i am from third app");
startActivity(i);
```

Or (depending which project you want to launch):

```
i.setAction("com.example.project.YOYO");
```

You can do it also via: (supply action directly in constructor)

```
i=new Intent("com.example.tictactoe.YOYO");
i.putExtra("KEY","HII..i am from third app");
startActivity(i);
```

Also loose the data mimeType or read up on how to use it. Because via putExtra is not going to work.

Comment: Remove the data attribute of  your XML and try again.

Comment: thanks....for all but it still not working..:p
could u please refer to any  link where a application is automatically started in response to the qualifying the implicit intent generated from  other application

Comment: We need to add Default Category in order to make Implicit intents work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to ensure that the name of the intent is the fully qualified name with the package name is the same in the intent filter and the activity firing the intent. In this case: "YOYO" should be "com.example.tictactoe.YOYO". You should also remove the mime type since you are not including data in the setData(), you are in this case using a bundle. So you should have for the activity firing the intent:

### ACTIVITY FIRING INTENT

```
i=new Intent();
i.setAction("com.example.tictactoe.YOYO");
i.putExtra("KEY","HII..i am from third app");
startActivity(i);
```

and for the receiving activity's entry in the manifest: You need to ensure you set the category as DEFAULT and remove the data type tag.

### ACTIVITY RECEIVING INTENT

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.example.tictactoe.YOYO" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```