# starting Intent(Context(), X.class); works whereas new Intent().setComponent(componentName) fails

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have an activity which I declare in my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
  <application>
    <activity
        android:name="com.my.InternalDummyActivity"
        android:exported="false">
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I have tried without the `exported=false` as well

The application contains an inner library with another activity.

I try to call an explicit intent from the other activity (other namespace)
But I always get an exception:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), InternalDummyActivity.class);
activity.startActivity(intent1);


ComponentName componentName2 =
    new ComponentName(
        "com.my","com.my.InternalDummyActivity");
Intent intent2 = new Intent().setComponent(componentName2); //dones work
activity.startActivity(intent2);


Process: com.comp.outter, PID: 9267
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.my/com.my.InternalDummyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: ```exported``` defaults to false if not present. Do both activities belong to the same package?

Comment: @JakeB `com.x.y.z` and `com.x.y.t` but it works when i launch it with the `intent(context, class)` signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ComponentName's [contructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#public-constructors) that takes a Context as parameter:

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context,
"com.my.InternalDummyActivity");
```

For some reason, you can use the contructor taking two Strings only if you know the class dynamically.

Comment: you can use the contructor taking two Strings only if you know the class dynamically ===> cannot (?)

Comment: Has this happened to you as well? what's the whole point of the string,string ctor then? I thought it's there for dynamic cases

Comment: you cannot use the contructor taking two Strings if you hardcode the class name. I think it's due to the compiler trying to pre build the ComponentName instance at compile time.

Comment: Then why this component ctor exist? for other cases using component (not for intent)? Does this not work for you as well when you try to construct `new intent(new Component(string,string))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your library should not know anything about package and class that is outside of the library. There is two solutions that will be better:

1. Use Implicit Intent. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25747414/10261731) for example
2. Create interface in your library with openScreen() method and implement it in another module were your Activity lies

Comment: then why this works? `Intent intent1 = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), InternalDummyActivity.class);
activity.startActivity(intent1);`